# Find weight 2 newforms with given coefficients using websites or softwares, if exists

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Given a finite set $P$ that consists of "small" prime numbers
$$P=\{p_1, ..., p_N\}.$$
Further if given integers $a_{p_i}$ for each $p_i \in P$, then are there websites or software that could give us the weight 2, eigenform of newform, for the group $\Gamma_0(N)$ (for some $N$) whose $p$-th coefficient in the $q$ expansion is $a_{p_i}$? Of course provide such a newform(s) exists.

Comment: @reuns Thank you, I have edited my question.

Comment: What for, of which weight k, eigenform of newform, as your question has a completely different meaning then. If $f$ is an eigenform (that is multiplicative coefficients) in $S_k(\Gamma_0(n))$ then $f(z)-c f(pz)$ is an eigenform in  $S_k(\Gamma_0(pn))$ so it is easy to set the $p$-th coefficient as we wish. But then if $f$ is a newform then $f(z)-c f(pz)$ isn't so for newforms it is much harder.

Comment: @reuns Thanks again. Weight 2 eigenform of newform.

Comment: I answered for eigenforms : pick any eigenform in $f \in S_k(\Gamma_0(n)), f(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} a_n(f) e^{2i \pi n z},a_1(f)=1, a_{nm}(f) = a_n(f)a_m(f)$ (for $gcd(n,m)=1$) then set $g(z) = \sum_{d | \prod_{j\le J} p_j} (\prod_{p_l | d} (c_l  -a_{p_l}) )f(d z)$ an eigenform $\in S_k(\Gamma_0(n \prod_{j=1}^J p_j))$. You should look at the corresponding Dirichlet series, assume $f$ is a newform so $L(s,f)$ has a functional equation similar to $\zeta(s)$ and deduce the one of $L(s,g)$